# Expresso Store Custom Field With Image

Tags: expresso-store, file-uploads, expresso, image, files

EE 5.3.0

Expresso Store 4.2.1

I have a store for replacement parts. Since customers might not always know what part they need, I would like to require users to post an image of the product for which they need parts when they check out.

I'm familiar with the `order_custom` fields but was wondering if it was possible to use these fields as image file uploads.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I developed a workaround that gets the job done.

Using a 3 page checkout process where the user must first submit a form with images and other details. That form has a hidden field with the cart id number so customer service will be sent the images, details, and cart id so they're able to compare the images to the order.

It's not ideal but considering I'm on a deadline this was the best I could come up with for the time being.

Comment: More detail on what you did would be helpful to others?